# Confused about String Replacing Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a url string formatted like the one below, and want to change the html entity ampersand `&#038;` into the symbol ampersand `&`.

```
var $url = "https://www.examplebiz.com/?utm_campaign=campaign&#038;parameter=m&#038;firstname=Jeremiah&#038;email=testemail@gmail.com"
```

When I tried string replace like the following, it didn't work:

```
$url = $url.replace(/&#038;/g , "&");
```

But, this worked perfectly:

```
$url = $url.replace(/#038;/g , "");
```

The first solution worked fine in js fiddle, but not on my site. Any idea what causes this?

**EDIT:** Here's the original code (no errors were thrown)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $( "#GK-Form" ).submit(function() { 
        var $name = $('input#last_name').val();
        var $email = $('input#email').val();
        var $url = 'https://www.examplebiz.com/?utm_campaign=campaign&parameter=m&firstname='+$name+'&email='+$email;
        $url = $url.replace(/&#038;/g , "&");           
        $( "input#ReturnUrl" ).val( $url );
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that the url is formatted properly before it's generated but then turns into the following. Also, this is done in a WordPress post (not sure if that makes a difference).

```
var $url = "https://www.examplebiz.com/?utm_campaign=campaign&#038;parameter=m&#038;firstname=Jeremiah&#038;email=testemail@gmail.com"
```

Comment: How does it "not work" on your site?  What happens?  Errors?  What does `$url` contain after that call?

Comment: After the call, the url remains unchanged, like there was no effect at all. I'm just wondering what could cause that problem

Comment: Probably it's an escaping problem - escape sequences inside of a `<script>` should not be interpreted like in "normal" html; if they are the script would mean `.replace(/&/g , "&")`. Can you show us how exactly you were including the script on your site?

Comment: Original code has been posted. Does this verify your suspicions?

Comment: What do you mean by "Note that the url is formatted properly before it's generated but then turns into the following." ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38NuS/3/) and it seems working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //    $( "#GK-Form" ).submit(function() { 
    var $name = 'lastname'; //$('input#last_name').val();
    var $email = 'email@dom.com'; //    $('input#email').val();
    var $url = 'https://www.examplebiz.com/?utm_campaign=campaign&#038;parameter=m&firstname=' + $name + '&email=' + $email;
    $url = $url.replace(/&#038;/g, "&");

    $("input#ReturnUrl").val($url);
    return true;
    //  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works fine for me in js fiddle, but not on my site. I'm wondering what could cause the replace to fail on my site, but not in something like js fiddle. As well, why does the first example above not work, but the second does?

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Please post the full source code that we can read it ?

Comment: Edited answer, still working for me... Provide the source code that is NOT working please (with values of inputs).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add in the most critical piece. Also, this worked great for me in js fiddle, the issue was only on my site. Input vals are just standard text for name and an email address for email field. Thanks for your help.